# How to display data from 2 different table as one list in view

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a page where I want to display images which are in the different table inside an image slider. But my images are displaying one after the other in rows. Is there a way to combine the list which comes from two different tables into one in view.

```
<div class="Slideshow">
@foreach (var table1 in Model.table1)
{
   <img src=@Url.Content(table1.imageurl) width="300"/>
}
@foreach (var table2 in Model.table2)
{
   <img src=@Url.Content(table2.imageurl) width="300" />
}
```

[image: DB table]

Comment: You'll have to join the tables in the backend of your application.

Comment: Union, not join.

Answer (score 2):

If your properties are the same type, you can concatenate them:

```
@foreach (var table1 in Model.table1.Concat(Model.table2))
```

If they're not the same type then you'd need to project them into a common type first.  Which could be something as simple as:

```
@foreach (var table1 in Model.table1.Select(t => t.imageurl).Concat(Model.table2.Select(t => t.imageurl)))
```

On a more stylistic note, this would ideally be something that happens in the model or controller instead of the view. The view should really just bind to the properties on the model and not need to manipulate them.

For example, you might add a calculated property to your model:

```
public IEnumerable<SomeType> Tables
{
    get { return table1.Contact(table2); }
}
```

Then in your view you'd just loop over `Model.Tables`. Or if you really only ever *need* one list of tables then your model should only have one and you should combine your different data sources when populating the model. But the more we dig into this the more assumptions we'd have to make about your data model at this point.